# Android on Gregorian Calendar

Tags: android

Guys I need help i want to display the month and date along with the day of following 7 days in format like

Sat - 22
Sun - 23
Mon - 24
..

Using a loop

what should be my approach within the loop ::

```
          Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
         for(i = 0;i<7;i++)
            {
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);     
            int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + i);  // Giving error here

            day[i] = dayOfMonth + month + "";
             }
```

I am totally a beginner in this field and im confused help me out

Comment: Do you need month name or week day name?

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + i);
```

to:

```
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + i;
```

Will fix the error.

But what you are trying to do can be better accomplished with:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // Adds a day to the date and takes care
                  // of adding month when its the last day of the month already

    int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // Get weekday name like Sunday
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    day[i] = weekDay + " - " + dayOfMonth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir One more thing I am getting an Error mssg; In this line Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); saying   "GregorianCalendar cannot be converted to Calendar" I am working on code block for sample test after than i will implement this in my Android studio and i  also have imported its class :    import java.util.Calendar;                                                          Before that am i required to do something i am sorry if its a stupid question.

Comment: You can change it to `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`